# Serving a JSON file content in Vue.js

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, static-files

I have a JSON file and I want to serve the content inside it when I hit a particular URL in Vue.js, but I do not want to involve any component into that, is there any possible solution for this ?

For example, I want a similar output to this practice in Django.

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

path("xyz", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="xyz.json",
                                            content_type="application/json"))
```

What I did currently is:

**index.js** in router

```
const TestDeepLink = () =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "Test-Deep-Link" */ "../components/TestDeepLink.vue")
const routes = [
  { path: '/test', component: TestDeepLink, name:"TestDeepLink"},]
```

**TestDeepLink.vue** in components

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span>{{myJson}}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import my_json from './xyz.json'
console.log('My data', my_json)
export default{
          data(){
              return{
                  myJson: my_json
              }
          }
      }
</script>
```

The above code is working fine , I just want to eliminate the component and want to serve the file content directly as we can do in django.

So the above code that I wrote in Vue worked absolutely fine but I do not want to involve component and want directly to render the JSON file content. Any possible solution will be heartly appreciated.

Comment: If you're using vuejs vanilla, you can't do that since you don't have a server, it's all client-side code. What you can do is either use a SSR framework like nuxtjs or upload the json file in the CDN server where you host your app.

Comment: @Kapcash, thanks for the solution , I am actually using Vuejs Vanilla, and I need to give that a backend, can you suggest me a good article/video from where I can add a server to the vuejs application.

Comment: How are you bundling and deploying your vuejs app right now? You could just try to add the file in the `public` folder to serve it as a [static asset](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder)

Comment: @Kapcash, already put that file in public folder, did not work out, what I did on your advice is I connected a express server with the Vue frontend, now how can I serve the file content using express server without involving the component in vue.